# Telegram бот на Python на определённом этапе не продолжает работу. Кто знает подскажите почему, где ошибка?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Telegram бот на Python на определённом этапе не продолжает работу. После нажатия на кнопку "Чай" ничего не происходит. Кто знает подскажите почему, гле ошибка?

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('Token')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Нажми чтобы выбрать напиток...")
    markup.add(btn1)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                     "Привет! Здесь ты можешь заказать напиток по своему вкусу",
                     reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == 'Нажми чтобы выбрать напиток...':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)  # создание новых кнопок
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Чай')
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Кофе')
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('На главную')
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Какой напиток предпочитаете...?', reply_markup=markup)  # ответ бота


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def sort_tee(message):
    if message.text == 'Чай':
        toock = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)  # создание новых кнопок
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Зелёный')
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Чёрный')
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Красный')
        btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('На главную')
        toock.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Какой чай предпочитаете...?', reply_markup=toock)  # ответ бота

    elif message.text == 'Зелёный':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                         '[Ваш напиток здесь...](https://lavka-coffee-tea.ru/catalog/zelenyj-chaj/)',
                         parse_mode='Markdown')

    elif message.text == 'Чёрный':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                         '[Ваш напиток здесь...](https://lavka-coffee-tea.ru/catalog/chernyj-chaj/)',
                         parse_mode='Markdown')

    elif message.text == 'Красный':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                         '[Ваш напиток здесь...](https://lavka-coffee-tea.ru/catalog/krasnyj/)',
                         parse_mode='Markdown')

    elif message.text == 'На главную':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, start(),
                         parse_mode='Markdown')


while True:
    bot.polling()  # обязательная для работы бота часть
```

Comment: функцию get_text_messages и sort_tee объединить под одним @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

Comment: К сожалению результат тот же...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что у вас два обработчика сообщений с типом `text`, и при получении любого текстового сообщения будет вызываться только первый из них (`gettextmessages`). Чтобы исправить это, нужно объединить обработчики в один, например, так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    if message.text == 'Нажми чтобы выбрать напиток...':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Чай')
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Кофе')
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('На главную')
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Какой напиток предпочитаете...?', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == 'Чай':
        toock = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Зелёный')
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Чёрный')
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Красный')
        btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('На главную')
        toock.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Какой чай предпочитаете...?', reply_markup=toock)

    elif message.text == 'Зелёный':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                         '[Ваш напиток здесь...](https://lavka-coffee-tea.ru/catalog/zelenyj-chaj/)',
                         parse_mode='Markdown')

    elif message.text == 'Чёрный':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                         '[Ваш напиток здесь...](https://lavka-coffee-tea.ru/catalog/chernyj-chaj/)',
                         parse_mode='Markdown')

    elif message.text == 'Красный':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                         '[Ваш напиток здесь...](https://lavka-coffee-tea.ru/catalog/krasnyj/)',
                         parse_mode='Markdown')

    elif message.text == 'На главную':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Нажми чтобы выбрать напиток...")
        markup.add(btn1)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                         "Привет! Здесь ты можешь заказать напиток по своему вкусу",
                         reply_markup=markup)
```

Также в функции "На главную" нужно использовать переменную `markup`, чтобы добавить кнопки выбора напитка.

Comment: Кстати, вам не стоит показывать токен для телеграм бота

Comment: elif message.text == 'На главную': start(message)

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: @VyacheslavSimdyanov, всегда рад помочь. Если ответ был вам полезен, то вы можете отметить его как решение и как полезный ответ. :)

Comment: Подскажите как отметить ваш ответ?

Comment: @VyacheslavSimdyanov Слева от ответа есть галочка при нажатии вы отмечаете, что ответ оказался верным. Для того чтобы отметить вопрос как полезный, вам нужно нажать на стрелочку вверх, находящуюся рядом с количеством оценок(На данный момент она равна нулю).